# Combine set -eux and set-a in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a shell script I inherited with the command

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
set -eux
```

I'd like to start sharing variables across various shell scripts that have to run congruently so I normally use this command to export variables in .env

```
set -a 
source .env
set +a
```

Is the appropriate syntax to combine:

```
set -euxa
source .env
set +a
```

Answer (score 1):

The `set` command modifies the shell attributes provided in the args.  It does not modify any attributes that you don't specify.  This means you can combine setting multiple attributes in one `set` invocation, or you can get the same results with multiple `set` invocations.

This syntax:

```bsh
set -e
set -u
set -x
set -a
```

will give you the exact same result as this:

```bsh
set -euxa
```

Stylistically, I'd recommend keeping the attributes that persist for the entire runtime of the script separate from any attributes you modify temporarily.  For your script, I'd recommend this:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
set -eux

set -a 
source .env
set +a
```